# Spring TestContext Framework

Tags: spring

i tried to create a test for loading applicationContext.xml using Spring TestContext Framework,the code is pretty simple:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/applicationContext.xml"})
public class ApplicationContextLoadingTest {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Ignore
    @Test
    public void testContext() {
    }
}
```

when i run the test i got the error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pollInitializer' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
...
```

any one knows what that means? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means exactly what it says: `applicationContext.xml` contains a bean named `pollInitializer`, this bean has an initialization method, that method tried to execute some Hibernate query, and the query failed with `SQLGrammarException`.

So, check Hibernate queries issued by that initialization method.

Answer (score 0):

It means that spring is loading the file applicationContect.xml and is it is failing to setup the bean named pollInitalizer which is defined in that file.

With your test you are attemptinhpg to auto wire an ApplicationContext. That is not really normal. Normally you would auto wire some beans defined in the XML that you caused to be loaded. You don't have to work with the application context directly.

Comment: the reason i auto wire the ApplicationContext is i want to test that file can be loaded successfully.